# R - How to make a subtable?

Tags: r

I have a table data1 that looks like :

```
V1 V2 V3
A  B  1
A  C  1
A  D  0
A  E  1
A  F  0
A  G  0
A  H  0
```

and I would like to extract a subtable data2 and keep all line where V3 == 1 like:

```
V1 V2 V3
A  B  1
A  C  1
A  E  1
```

I did it by using a loop but it's not very elegant.

How to do this without a complex loop?

Comment: Assuming your data frame is `df` then `df[df$V3==1, ]`

Comment: This kind of subsetting is essential to learn if you want to do any analysis in R so you might want to also consult an introductory tutorial to R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this in R.
The most common ones are listed below.

```
# Selecting observations on conditions
data2 <- data1[V3 == 1, ]

# Excluding observations on conditions
data2 <- data1[!V3 != 1, ]

# Subset function
data2 <- subset(data1, V3 == 1)

#using packages:

# dplyr package
library(dplyr)
data2 <- filter(data1, V3 == 1)

# data.table package
library(data.table)
data2 <- setDT(data1)[V3 == 1]
```

Most R-users don't use the `subset` function for reasons mentioned in this post: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

Answer (score 1):

You can use subset function:

```
data2 <- subset (data1, V3 == 1)
```

***Data***

```
data <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                   V2=c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
                   V3=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: beware of the "dangers" of `subset`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: Agree there are a lot of ways to do that