# how subset a data frame by the column using a character string

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame in R like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(cbind(C.01=1, C.02=1:8, C.03=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")))
```

And I would obtain a subset like this:

```
> subset(df, C.03 == "A")

C.01 C.02 C.03
1    1    1    A
```

It's possible do the same subset but having the name of the column in `xx <- "C.03"` ??

Because `subset(df, xx == "A")` doesn't works.

Thnks.

Comment: Could do `df[df[xx] == "A", ]`

Comment: Avoid using `subset` and use standard `[` and `[[` operators, like @DavidArenburg suggests. Also `df[df[[xx]]=="A",]` works in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract a subset of a data frame based on a condition involving a field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540658/r-how-to-make-a-subtable/29541508#29541508 just remember to put the string in quotation marks `".."`

Comment: I would strongly advise to use either David's or nicola's solution but, if you really want to use `subset`, you could try `subset(df,eval(parse(text=paste0(xx,"==","\"A\""))))`. However, this kind of hacky code ultimately eliminates `subset`'s main advantage of better readability. Using `subset` might also cause unexpected behaviour (see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset).

Answer (score 3):

Using base R (thanks @David Arenburg):

```
df[df[xx] == "A", ]
```

Or with `dplyr`, which I suggest because the syntax is easier to make sense of:

```
require("dplyr")
df <- filter(df, C.03 == "A")
```